# Specify JVisualVM Heap Dump File Location on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvisualvm

The default location for JVisualVM's heapdump files in Linux is the /tmp/ directory. Because of my development machine's limitations, and the resource use of my application /tmp/ isn't big enough to capture the file. Is there a way to set this as a parameter in JVisualVM?

I'm looking for something like:

```
./jvisualvm --heaplocation /my/desired/location
```

I have created a symlink to the default location using the following:

```
ln -sf /my/desired/location/visualvm.dat
```

However, that is an ugly hack. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify it in the file `${VISUALVM_HOME}/etc/visualvm.conf`

Search for the line starting with `visualvm_default_options` and add the setting to the end of the line (must be between the double quotes).

```
visualvm_default_options="... -J-Dvisualvm.tmpdir=/where/you/want"
```

**note** the `...` are a placeholder for the existing settings

The information has been taken from the property `VISUALVM_TMP_DIR` in the class [Storage.java](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/blob/master/visualvm/core/src/com/sun/tools/visualvm/core/datasource/Storage.java)